# Flask-WTForms: populating a FileField field

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, werkzeug

I have a form using WTF-Forms on Flask such as:

```py
class ImageForm(FlaskForm):
    """Form used for image uploading"""

    image = FileField(
        validators=[
            FileRequired(),
            FileAllowed(["png", "jpg", "jpeg"], "This file is not a valid image !",),
        ],
        render_kw={"class": "form-control-file border"},
    )
    patient_ID = StringField(
        "patient_ID",
        validators=[DataRequired()],
        render_kw={"placeholder": "Patient ID", "class": "form-control"},
    )
    submit = SubmitField("Upload", render_kw={"class": "btn btn-primary mb-2"})
```

It works great when filled in.
However I want people to be able to modify the informations later on. So what I do is that if the form page is opened with a GET args such as id=1, I prefill the form with the informations stored such as:

```py
if request.args:
        image_request = Image.query.get(request.args.get("id"))
        # Check that image exists in DB and prepare the FileStoage object.
        if image_request is not None:
            file = None
            with open(image_request.image_path, "rb") as fp:
                file = FileStorage(fp)
            form = ImageForm(
                image=file,
                patient_ID=image_request.patient_id)
```

It works for patient_ID it is correctly filled. However the "image" field stay UnboundFile.

```py
print(type(file))
print(file)
print(type(ImageForm.image))
print(ImageForm.image)
```

Gives:

```
<class 'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage'>
<FileStorage: '/home/xxx/xxx/data/hkjhk/hkjhk_dog.jpg' (None)>
<class 'wtforms.fields.core.UnboundField'>
<UnboundField(FileField, (), {'validators': [<flask_wtf.file.FileRequired object at 0x7f170969fb20>, <flask_wtf.file.FileAllowed object at 0x7f170969ffd0>], 'render_kw': {'class': 'form-control-file border'}})>
```

Has anyone experience on how to prefill a FileStorage field ?
Can you help me with it ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is very late, but I'm writing this answer cause I was stuck on the same issue. for security reasons, the browser doesn't accept a prefilled FileField. You need to show the image with html and the keep the FileField for updating the image.
To know if the FileField contains a new file storage you can check for its type. If it is a string then no new file is inserted:

```
if imageForm.image.data and not sinstance(form.imageFile.data, str):
    # here you have a new image file
else:
    # here the FileField contains a string or is empty meaning that the
    # user has no intention of changing or adding a file.
```

I hope this is clear and will help someone.